# How to avoid losing the horizontal scrollbar position on a datagrid after loading new data and visualising the loading indicator while loading

Tags: gwt

I am using a datagrid and an asynchronous data provider to display a very long chunk of data stored in a database. To avoid continuously requesting data from the database, a cache is being used. This cache only contains a portion of the real data, so the data is loaded in as it is needed.

To pretend that the datagrid contains all the real data and not having to render it all, a new widget has been created and incorporated to the view where the datagrid is displayed.

This widget simulates a vertical scrollbar that allows the user to browse all the data, even data that is not at the moment in the cache. So the datagrid always has the same number of rows, and all of them are visible. Whereas the cache contains the visible rows plus the nearest data before and after the data that it is visible.

Consequently, when the scroller is moved to a position that is not in the cache, a request to the database is done and the text 'loading...' appears as part of the loading indicator that the datagrid has. But when this happens, if the datagrid was wider than the width of screen, the horizontal scroll that the datagrid includes appears, and once I get back the data and it is displayed, I lose the position of the horizontal scrollbar I had.

So the horizontal scrollbar is always positioned at the beginning after loading data into the cache. I have tried to store the position of the horizontal scrollbar before showing 'loading...' and then restore it, but as it is possible to keep doing multiple calls, as many as mouse movements are detected while holding the scroller, I cannot tell when I am storing the initial position or the position resulting of showing 'loading...'.

Any ideas what could it be done to stop the scrollbar changing its position or how to restore the position it has before loading new data?

Comment: How do you refresh the DataGrid when a new portion of data is loaded?

Comment: To update the DataGrid I use the methods `updateRowData(0, data)` and `updateRowCount(data.size(), true)` from the asynchronous data provider.

Answer (score 1):

What I did, and works fine for me ;-),

```
import com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.DataGrid;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.CustomScrollPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HeaderPanel;

public class MyDataGrid<T> extends DataGrid<T> {

private int scrollBarPositionV;
private int scrollBarPositionH;

public void saveScrollBarPosition() {
    final HeaderPanel panel = (HeaderPanel) getWidget();
    final CustomScrollPanel bodyContent = (CustomScrollPanel) panel.getContentWidget();
    scrollBarPositionH = bodyContent.getHorizontalScrollPosition();
    scrollBarPositionV = bodyContent.getVerticalScrollPosition();
}

public void restoreScrollBarPosition() {
    final HeaderPanel panel = (HeaderPanel) getWidget();
    final CustomScrollPanel bodyContent = (CustomScrollPanel) panel.getContentWidget();
    bodyContent.setHorizontalScrollPosition(scrollBarPositionH);
    bodyContent.setVerticalScrollPosition(scrollBarPositionV);
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Only one comment: the scroll position should be restored after the element is rendered. Timer can be used with some interval, and restoreScrollBarPosition() should be called from run() method of this timer.

Answer (score 0):

[DataGrid](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/DataGrid.html) doesnot provide api to capture horizontal scroll bar position.

[ScrollPanel](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ScrollPanel.html) in GWT, which provides api to capture horizontal and vertical scroll position.

Try this workaround

1) Add your datagrid into the scroll panel

2) Capture the horizontal scroll position before invoking the request to the database to retrieve records. Use method [getHorizontalScrollPosition()](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ScrollPanel.html#getHorizontalScrollPosition())

3) On successful completion of DB request, load the records in the appropriate object(datagrid)

4) Reset the scroll panel horizontal position using [setHorizontalScrollPosition()](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ScrollPanel.html#setHorizontalScrollPosition(int))

Hope it Helps!!

Comment: By extending the datagrid class and:

Comment: `final HeaderPanel panel = (HeaderPanel) getWidget();
bodyContent = (CustomScrollPanel) panel.getContentWidget();`
in the constructor I can:
`bodyContent.getHorizontalScrollbar()`
and store it in a variable to use it. But then it is when, "after doing multiple calls, as many as mouse movements are detected while holding the scroller, I cannot tell if I am storing the initial position or the position resulting of showing 'loading...'."

Comment: Always capture the scroll bar position just before invoking the request(to load more data), then once the response is received set the scroll bar position.